# Filter invalid Ids from a list of string for both oracle and postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I have a list of Ids as Input

```
id1, id2 ,id3, id5, id6
```

My table has

```
id1, id2, id3, id6
```

Result expected `id5`

I want a single query compatible with both Postgres and Oracle

Comment: you can use `not exists` or `not in` .

Comment: can you provide a solution ? My input is a list of array  and I need to filter the invalid ids from the input .

Comment: Is the input a single comma separated string? And is the data also stored that way?

Comment: input is a array of ids

Comment: There is no way you will find a query that runs unchanged on Postgres **and** Oracle. It's extremely easy with Postgres, but quite complicated with Oracle

Comment: And how is the data stored? Also as a comma separated list? Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) in a table like manner (how a SQL client would display it) to avoid confusion. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: please add a sample for the input, and how you tried to manipulate within the code.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is the string and your table has string ids then you can use the following query in Oracle.

```
SQL>
SQL> with ids as (
  2  select trim(regexp_substr('id1, id2 ,id3, id5, id6','[^,]+', 1, level)) ids from dual
  3     connect by regexp_substr('id1, id2 ,id3, id5, id6', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
  4  ),
  5  my_table_ids as
  6  (select trim(regexp_substr('id1, id2, id3, id6','[^,]+', 1, level)) ids from dual
  7     connect by regexp_substr('id1, id2, id3, id6', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
  8  select ids from ids
  9  minus
 10  select ids from my_table_ids;

IDS
-----------
id5

SQL>
```

Cheers!!